# Schema Crawler issue in sc.sh

Tags: database-schema, schema-compare, schemacrawler

I am trying to get a text dump of Oracle Database schema using SchemaCrawler utility from SourceForge. Supplied the below args at command line

```
./sc.sh -driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver 
-host=<hostName> 
-port=<portNumber> 
-database=iknowit 
-schemas=IM_OWNER 
-user=im_owner 
-password=im_owner 
-table_types=TABLE,VIEW 
-infolevel=maximum 
-command=schema > dump-AF_ITA.txt
```

However this gets stuck at a particular point and looks like an infinite loop

Exception in schemacrawler.schema.IndexColumnSortSequence valueOfFromCode

unknown code null

Comment: Since this may require some back and forth, you may want to post the question on the SchemaCrawler support forums, http://sourceforge.net/p/schemacrawler/discussion/495991/

Comment: Thanks @SualehFatehi and Done..posted at https://sourceforge.net/p/schemacrawler/discussion/495990/thread/b4781831/

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Sualeh Fatehi on https://sourceforge.net/p/schemacrawler/discussion/495990/thread/b4781831/ I used -loglevel=ALL and -infolevel=standard rather than minimum as suggested.

Also initially I observed that I got only the table names, I then modified schemacrawler.config.properties and set all text formatting options to true as I needed the whole table definition

```
schemacrawler.format.show_unqualified_names=true
schemacrawler.format.hide_primarykey_names=true
schemacrawler.format.hide_foreignkey_names=true
schemacrawler.format.hide_index_names=true
schemacrawler.format.hide_constraint_names=true
```

That did the job!

Thanks to Sualeh Fatehi for providing help and for such a great configurable utility.

Cheers,
Heena

Comment: Heena, -loglevel=ALL is only for debugging. If you are not debugging SchemaCrawler, you can omit it, since it will only slow things down.